# How to do api call request to get data of a set of objects in nodeJs

Tags: node.js, api

Giving a partner API backend, where are stored un set of object with their informations.
I can get by an api request information of one object in format JSON.
My problem is how can I get all information of all objects.
The code below is built to get information of one object:

```
module.exports.getBackendData = function (request, response) {
    var deviceid = request.params.id_device;
    var id = request.params._id;
    var points = [];
    var optionsget = {
        host: 'hostname', //here only the domain name
        port: 443
        , path: '/api/partner/' + id + '', //the rest of the url parameters if needed 
        method: 'GET', //do GET
        auth: 'username:password'
    };
    var myRequest = https.request(optionsget, function (myResponse) {
        var myData = '';

        myResponse.on('data', function (d) {
            myData += d;
        });

        myResponse.on('end', function () {
            str = JSON.parse(myData);
            var lat, long, statut, timestamp;
            for (var i = 0; i <= str.reports.length - 1; i++) {
                lat = str.reports[i].latitude;
                long = str.reports[i].longitude;
                timestamp = str.reports[i].ts;
                statut = str.reports[i].move;

                locations.push({
                    long: long
                    , latitude: lat
                    , move: statut
                    , timestamp: timestamp
                });
            }

            response.json(points);
        });
    });
    myRequest.end();
    myRequest.on('error', function (e) {
        console.error("error:", e);
    });
}
```

As api call is done asynchronously I don't know how to get one time response of all objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classic "how to deal with nodes asynchronous nature in a loop" questions.

Look at library's like `async` or `steed`, Promises, Async / Await.
In any case your `"list of objects IDs"` is missing, if I can infer this right from your question.

Likely the most performant and friendly way for the API is to do them one by one.

I'd go for

```
const steed = require('steed')()

const ids = [1, 2, 3]

function makeHttpRequest (id, cb) {
  // as in your example
  return locations
}

steed.mapSeries(ids, function (id, cb) {
  makeHttpRequest(id, cb)
}, (err, result) => {
  if (err) return console.log(err)
  // result is an array of all the resutls of the single calls
  console.log(result)
})
```

Comment: My list of objects is like this: ids = [{"_id":"_id", "devid": "devid_value"},...{}]

Comment: then more or less this applies.Just reference the id instead of the array value.